# Static HTML page in ASP.NET MVC that does not use Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an entire Web Application built using ASP.NET MVC and have a `_ViewStart.cshtml` page that specifies a Layout.

This works great for my entire site.  However, I have a single prototype static HTML page that I just need to dump into a directory.

I copied the HTML into a CSHTML file and fronted it with a controller.  The problem is that when I go to this page, it is using the Layout.

How can I configure it so that I can just serve this page up as static, standalone content without the Layout from `_ViewStart`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all views will use the layout from `~/Views/Shared` as it is specified in the `_Viewstart.cshtml` file. Every time a view is executed, the code inside the  `_Viewstart.cshtml` will be executed which sets the layout for the view.

If you do not want to execute/include the layout for a specific view, you can explicitly set layout as `null` on a view. Add the below code to the view.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Keep in mind that, even though it is static html in your `cshtml` file, user will not/should not directly access this view (like a normal html page/htm page). It has to be routed via an action method which returns this `cshtml` view.

Another option is to use the `PartialView` method instead of `View` method. When using the PartialView method to render a view, the framework do not run `_ViewStart.cshtml`, hence you get the same result.

```
public ActionResult About()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

[`PartialView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial) is really handy when you want to render the markup for parts of your page (Ex : content of for a modal dialog etc)

Answer (score 0):

In your static view page set layout = null. 
Like: 
`@{Layout = null;}`